# Joins in hibernate HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, jpql

I have the following mysql query :

```
SELECT s.file, sheet, s.messagetemplate,s.time_to_run,s.frequency,s.schedule_name, t.Value 
FROM  s   INNER JOIN  tFrequencies t ON s.frequencyId=t.id
```

My need is to implement this in hibernate. I look for a simple to understand answer being a beginner. I wouldn't understand prior complex implementations. Thanks. 
package com.mspace1.model;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;    
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author support
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "tFrequencies")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "TFrequencies.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM TFrequencies t")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "TFrequencies.findById", query = "SELECT t FROM TFrequencies t WHERE t.id = :id")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "TFrequencies.findByValue", query = "SELECT t FROM TFrequencies t WHERE t.value = :value")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "TFrequencies.findByDescription", query = "SELECT t FROM TFrequencies t WHERE t.description = :description")})
public class TFrequencies implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 11)
    @Column(name = "Value")
    private String value;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "Description")
    private String description;

    private List <tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule> schedule;

    public TFrequencies() {
    }

    public TFrequencies(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public TFrequencies(Integer id, String value, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public List<tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule> getSchedule() {
        return schedule;
    }

    public void setSchedule(List<tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule> schedule) {
        this.schedule = schedule;
    }



    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof TFrequencies)) {
            return false;
        }
        TFrequencies other = (TFrequencies) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.mspace1.model.TFrequencies[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){

    }
}
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mspace1.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author support
 */
@Entity
@Table(catalog = "dbSMS", schema = "")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule t")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule.findById", query = "SELECT t FROM tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule t WHERE t.id = :id")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule.findBySheet", query = "SELECT t FROM tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule t WHERE t.sheet = :sheet")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule.findByMobileColumn", query = "SELECT t FROM tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule t WHERE t.mobileColumn = :mobileColumn")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule.findByTimeTosend", query = "SELECT t FROM tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule t WHERE t.timeTosend = :timeTosend")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule.findByUser", query = "SELECT t FROM tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule t WHERE t.user = :user")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule.findBySource", query = "SELECT t FROM tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule t WHERE t.source = :source")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule.findByDeliverFrequency", query = "SELECT t FROM tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule t WHERE t.deliverFrequency = :deliverFrequency")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule.findByTimeToRun", query = "SELECT t FROM tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule t WHERE t.timeToRun = :timeToRun")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule.findByProcessed", query = "SELECT t FROM tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule t WHERE t.processed = :processed")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule.findByFrequency", query = "SELECT t FROM tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule t WHERE t.frequency = :frequency")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule.findByFrequencyId", query = "SELECT t FROM tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule t WHERE t.frequencyId = :frequencyId")
, @NamedQuery(name = "tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule.findByFrequencyName", query = "SELECT t FROM tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule t WHERE t.frequencyName = :frequencyName")})
public class tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule implements Serializable {





    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)

    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 65535)
    private String file;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String sheet;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String mobileColumn;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 65535)
    private String messagetemplate;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date timeTosend;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String user;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String source;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int deliverFrequency;
    @Column(name = "time_to_run")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date timeToRun;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private short processed;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private short frequency;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int frequencyId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
    @Column(name = "schedule_name", nullable = false, length = 65535)
    private String scheduleName;
    private String frequencyName;
    public tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule() {
    }

    public tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule(Integer id, String file, String sheet, String mobileColumn, String messagetemplate, Date timeTosend, String user, String source, int deliverFrequency, short processed, short frequency, int frequencyId,String frequencyName, String scheduleName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.file = file;
        this.sheet = sheet;
        this.mobileColumn = mobileColumn;
        this.messagetemplate = messagetemplate;
        this.timeTosend = timeTosend;
        this.user = user;
        this.source = source;
        this.deliverFrequency = deliverFrequency;
        this.processed = processed;
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.frequencyId = frequencyId;
        this.scheduleName = scheduleName;
        this.frequencyName=frequencyName;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(String file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public String getSheet() {
        return sheet;
    }

    public void setSheet(String sheet) {
        this.sheet = sheet;
    }

    public String getMobileColumn() {
        return mobileColumn;
    }

    public void setMobileColumn(String mobileColumn) {
        this.mobileColumn = mobileColumn;
    }

    public String getMessagetemplate() {
        return messagetemplate;
    }

    public void setMessagetemplate(String messagetemplate) {
        this.messagetemplate = messagetemplate;
    }

    public Date getTimeTosend() {
        return timeTosend;
    }

    public void setTimeTosend(Date timeTosend) {
        this.timeTosend = timeTosend;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public int getDeliverFrequency() {
        return deliverFrequency;
    }

    public void setDeliverFrequency(int deliverFrequency) {
        this.deliverFrequency = deliverFrequency;
    }

    public Date getTimeToRun() {
        return timeToRun;
    }

    public void setTimeToRun(Date timeToRun) {
        this.timeToRun = timeToRun;
    }

    public short getProcessed() {
        return processed;
    }

    public void setProcessed(short processed) {
        this.processed = processed;
    }

    public short getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    public void setFrequency(short frequency) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    public int getFrequencyId() {
        return frequencyId;
    }

    public void setFrequencyId(int frequencyId) {
        this.frequencyId = frequencyId;
    }

    public String getScheduleName() {
        return scheduleName;
    }

    public void setScheduleName(String scheduleName) {
        this.scheduleName = scheduleName;
    }

    public String getFrequencyName() {
        return frequencyName;
    }

    public void setFrequencyName(String frequencyName) {
        this.frequencyName = frequencyName;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule)) {
            return false;
        }
        tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule other = (tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.mspace1.model.tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

I have edited my question to add the two entities I am using. The first entity contains frequencies which I want to join with selected item from the the other entity. TFrequency table has a constant values that don't change.This frequency is mapped to tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule entity using ID. However, I want to select name from TFrequency and not the mapped id. This I then use to populate my data-table. Do I need to create a third entity? I am not sure how this works and I have been trying joins around with no success.

Comment: Can you show your hibernate entities? What you already tried?

Comment: First Entity is:

Comment: Hi Dherik, I have updated the question my mysql would be: select  e.*,f.Value from tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule e join tFrequencies f on e.frequencyId=f.id

Comment: What version of Hibernate do you use? Joins are possible in the latest versions of it.

Comment: Hibernate 4.3.1 ...

Answer (score 1):

To do this in the "hibernate way", you need to map the `tFrequencies` table in a entity to get the `Value` from `tFrequencies`, creating a relationship to `tFrequencies`.

After that, if you not bother to return the entire entity `tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule`, you can do:

```
SELECT s FROM tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule s 
JOIN s.tFrequencies t
where t.id = :idFrequency
```

After the query returned the result, you can access the `Value` from `tFrequencies` by the `tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule`:

```
tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule.getTFrequencies().getValue();
```

**Tip**: If you are using the Hibernate version 5.1 or superior, you [don't need the relationship](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-join-unrelated-entities/) to do the JOIN.

## Without return the entire entity

If you don't want to return the entire entity, you can pass only the informations you want using the [Object array](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-join-unrelated-entities/), [Hibernate Tuple](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) or a [specific Dto](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) to handle that. Using Dto, the code is like:

```
List<PostDTO> postDTOs = entityManager.createQuery(
"select new " +
"   com.páckage.ExcelDto("+
"       s.file, " +
"       s.sheet " + //TODO add the other attributes
"   ) " +
"from tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule s JOIN s.tFrequencies t" +
"where t.id = :idFrequency")
.setParameter("idFrequency", 1).getResultList();
```

## Without mapping the table into entity

It's also possible doing that without entities (using native SQL), by the [ResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13904), passing the informations to a DTO too.

Comment: Well, not entirely true as it is possible to use joins with the latest versions of Hibernate between entities that are not linked on the object model level or the relationship is one way only.

Comment: @Jagger, I edited my answer to add this information. Thank you, I didn't know that.

Comment: Thanks @Dherik and Jagger, I achieved this using 'Without return the entire entity' way and my datatable is now populated from the two tables appropriately.  This introduced a new issue in a delete button in my table, it cannot delete using ID as previously done. I understand that this is caused by table being loaded from two entity classes. I am still working round the issue, however, I would appreciate if any of you has an idea on how to go about it....

Comment: @MartinMaina, maybe you need to create a new question, because there a some details that is necessary to understand the problem. For instance, to delete you only need to find the entity by id and call the `delete` method (from hibernate session or entity manager)

Comment: @Dherik Thanks, I have achieved this by passing id for tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule entity to my new class holding values for the join between tEXCELSMSTOSENDSchedule and tFrequencies, it was pretty easy after understanding above.

Comment: @MartinMaina, nice! Could you accept my answer? Thanks!